# Azure NSG rules not being applied to my VM

Tags: networking, remote-desktop, azure

I have a test environment I spun up on Azure but I cannot seem to RDP to the VM.  I verified the port is enabled inbound on my network security group for the subnet, and the NSG for the NIC.  I re-created the NIC and applied the same rules.  There is no external or third party firewall on this deployment. It is working on another VM on the same subscription that was cloned from this one, so it appears to only be VM specific.

I also disabled the guest OS firewall using the azure guides here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/disable-guest-os-firewall-windows

I verified that port 3389 is enabled inbound on the guest os (even though its off).

As a test, I enabled port 3389 from the internet (all ips) and I did a port scan with Kali Linux and I don't see that port as open, even though the NSG and the NIC should allow all traffic on that port.

I've also redeployed this VM, reset the RDP configuration, reset the user configuration, and basically exhausted the msft troubleshooting guide: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/troubleshooting/troubleshoot-rdp-connection

So in summary, I verified the Windows Firewall is OFF, and that the port is allowed on the NSG and the NIC and there is no external firewall. However, the port does not show as open when using a port scanner.  Since the Guest OS firewall is ruled out as an issue, it appears that the network security group isn't applying rules correctly to this VM.  How can I rectify this?

Comment: Are you trying to connect from a corporate LAN?

Comment: I tried my corporate LAN, from Starbucks, and at my house and still no dice.  I ran Kali from my house to do a port scan and it didn't show any ports open, but my NSG rules should allow all traffic from anywhere on that port.